# Two icon visible on ios for same application

Tags: ios, iphone

With an application in the application upgrade, there are two icon.
Under good network conditions,  icon update will disappear, otherwise next time you update icon will automatically disappear. It cannot be removed manually.
Restart the device is invalid. The same certificate and bundle identifier.
Sorry,I have no reputation to upload image.
This apple forums address:https://devforums.apple.com/message/1115409

Comment: Please add some screenshots, more detailed description where is your `application upgrade` and what you are doing in general. Right now it is not clear

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to upload image.  This is apple developer forumes address:https://devforums.apple.com/message/1115409

Comment: You seem to be describing a behaviour that is sometimes seen when iOS apps update. What is your question?  Do you want to know what it means? Whether it is a problem? How to stop it?

Comment: How to stop it, I don't want to see two icon,  and I hope in the original icon display updates. Because sometimes the second icon will not disappear, and can not be deleted manually. Thank you.